# Triangle inequality in norms

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

> Let $N:V\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of norms and
>
> $d(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\frac{N_{j}(y-x)}{1+N_j(x)+N_j(y)}$
>
> Show that $d(x,z)\leq{d(x,y)}+d(y,z)$

I tried the following

$d(x,z)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\frac{N_{j}(z-x)}{1+N_j(x)+N_j(z)}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\frac{N_{j}((z-y)+(y-x))}{1+N_j(x)+N_j(z)}\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\frac{N_{j}(z-y)+N_{j}(y-x)}{1+N_j(x)+N_j(z)}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\frac{N_{j}(z-y)}{1+N_j(x)+N_j(z)}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\frac{N_{j}(y-x)}{1+N_j(x)+N_j(z)}$

I do not know how to continue

Comment: Is the distance supposed to be defined as $d(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\frac{N_{j}(x-y)}{1 + N_{j}(x-y)}$ or you meant what you wrote above?

Comment: Yes, the distance is defined as above

Comment: You can try to mimick coming up with similar inqualities that are used in proving the other one I had mentioned above: If $a, b, c \geq 0, c \leq a + b$, then $\frac{c}{1 +c} \leq \frac{a}{1 + a + b} + \frac{b}{1 + a + b} \leq \frac{a}{1 + a} + \frac{b}{1 + b}$.